# Taking string as input and converting to time/date in java

Tags: java, java-time

When I take the string input using `next()`, I don't get any exception

```
String a=sc.next()
SimpleDateFormat b=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
b.parse(a);
System.out.println(b.format(b.parse(a)));
```

But when I take the input using `nextLine()` method of Scanner class, I get an exception

```
String a=sc.nextLine()
SimpleDateFormat b=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
b.parse(a);
System.out.println(b.format(b.parse(a)));
```

How to fix this, I get the same exception when using `sc.nextLine()` and date format as `"hh:mm a"`

Comment: What exception are you getting? What does the scanner actually read in? is it user input or are you reading data from a file?

Comment: It is user input...java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""...This is the exception I'm getting.Actually the question says " The first line of each test case contains a single time P " and the time is of the form "hh:mm a" (eg 10:43 AM)...Can't figure out how to take this input.

Comment: O please, stop using `SimpleDateFormat`. That class, just like `Date` and `Calendar`, is outdated and [troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api). Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For better reception of your next questions you will want to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before posting.

Answer (score 1):

This problem maybe related to how the `Scanner` works.
See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) of `next`:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is **preceded** and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

and of `nextLine`:

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.

The default delimiter includes the newline character (`\n`).

I assume the input has a leading newline (empty line) that is being *removed* by `next` but not by `nextLine`.

Test:

- `new Scanner("\ntest\n").next()` returns `"test"`
- `new Scanner("\ntest\n").nextLine()` returns `""` (empty string)

This will happen, for example, if the previous `Scanner` input was read with `nextInt()` (or similar) - this does not *consume* any newline after the number:

```
var sc = new Scanner("123\n456\n");
var i = sc.nextInt();  // will be 123
var str = sc.nextLine();  // will be the empty string "" (between 123 and \n)
str = sc.nextLine();  // now it is "test"
```

<sub>`String` used as input for the `Scanner` since it is easier to describe, same will happen with user input where a newline will be read if user types the return key (usually to end input)</sub>

If this is the case, solution is to call `nextLine()` after reading a number <sub>(or even read the number with `nextLine()` and then parsing it)</sub>.

For more details, please check this question: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/13510609)

<sub>this answer is based on the comment that the Exception mentions the empty string `""`  as unparseable</sub> 
 also consider vsfDawg's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66106902/13510609) - `next()` will stop at whitespace character

Comment: BTW `"dd/MM/yyyy"` will not parse time

Answer (score 0):

If your input looks like this:

```
10/12/2020 11:59:59 am
```

Then the first invocation of the `Scanner` `next()` method would return `"10/12/2020"` while the first invocation of `nextLine()` would return `"10/12/2020 11:59 am"`.  The former matches your `DateFormat` while the latter does not.  That is *may* be why `next()` is behaving but you get an Exception with `nextLine()`.